# How to write this method in separate module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I have this method in specific model.

```
self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |association|
  define_method "#{association.name}?" do
    self.send(association.name).any?
  end
end
```

I want to use this method in every model. How can I write this method in separate module ?

Answer (score 0):

Untested and from memory, but the following should work

```
module ReflectOnAssocations
    def included(base)
        base.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |association|
            define_method "#{association.name}?" do
                self.send(association.name).any?
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: are you including it in all of your models? What is the error message?

Comment: The method should be `self.included`

Comment: And you should call `base.define_method`, otherwise it will define a method on the module and hence this method will be shared across all classes that include that module.

Comment: @semyon: apparently my in-brain rails install is corrupted :) I was thinking i needed base.send(:define_method) (define_method is private last time i checked), but couldn't remember for sure

Comment: Agreed. I chose to use `include` because I prefer to use include when defining instance methods, and extend for class methods. Also, wouldn't the extend approach cause all models to have all #{association.name}? methods

Comment: Bohdan, just `define_method` will define a method for all classes that include that module, `extend` will not help.

Comment: I want this method should be available to all the active record models without include this module on each and every model.